# endless ndless list-like display/edit area with database records

Tags: database, swing, list

I am doing a pet project which needs to sync record with a JDBC database. I would like to have a endless list-like display/edit area which is 1-to-1 matched with records in database. This area will include a. JLabel("name"), JTextField(10), b. JLabel("Address"), JTextArea(20,30)  etc.  And there should be vertical scroll bar to scroll records up- and downward.

This is actually possible with Microsoft-Access, but is it also possible with JAVA

Thanks a lot!

Steven

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `JTable` for this sort of thing.  [Here is a tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to get you started.

Comment: thanks for the tip. But I don't want a table/grid, but a neatly organized field-input area.